# content share in LinkedIn not displaying the image

Tags: share, linkedin-api

I added the tag in my page but it not fetching the image while LinkedIn sharing .

I want to know to how to customize a image while share in LinkedIn using.

http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true'+'&url='+articleUrl+'&title='+articleTitle+      '&summary='+articleSummary+'&source='+articleSource

please let me know what to do fetch the image while sharing on LinkedIn.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?token&isFramed=false&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwpsites.net%2Fweb-design%2Fstyle-jetpacks-social-sharing-sharedaddy-buttons%2F

use this on browser its work with image.

in url that you like to share that page required image then and then only image will display on share tabs

URL that you like to share that must be live on net.

image auto fetch from given URL. please try with some valid url that have image tag

Answer (score 0):

Use the metatags on your html page to indicate the crawler how to present the link, there's an image property too:

```html
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
  <meta property="og:title" content="My Shared Article Title" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Description of shared article" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/my_article.html" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/foo.jpg" />
</head>
<body>
   …
</body>
</html>
```

Source: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin#methods